# What does "GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE should be used in NPOT textures" mean?

Tags: opengl

I have two sRGB PNG images I am using for textures. One is 64x64, and works fine. The other is 64x47, and when I attempt to use it I get an error:

```
reason: 'GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE should be used in NPOT textures'
```

What does this mean, and how do I address it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that where you call `glTexParameteri` with `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` or `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T`, you are specifying a value *other than* `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` (such as `GL_REPEAT`), which is not supported for textures with dimensions that are not powers of two (64 is a power of two, but 47 is not, thus your second texture is a "NPOT" or "non-power-of-two" texture).

To fix this, either pass `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` for that texture or alter the source texture's dimensions to be powers of two. This is usually done most easily by simply expanding the offending dimension up to the next available power of two.

Comment: i change the value of npot in my project (CCConfiguration.m) it accept all image in my project 
#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
supportsNPOT_ = NO;
in this changes any problem occur in future..?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with that, but I would guess that causes your API to extend all NPOT texture dimensions, in which case it will alleviate the problem.